# Get only city name in Autocomplete suggestions using Google Places API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am using the below code to get the city suggestion but it's giving me the city + state + country, but I need only city name

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
        var autocomplete;
        function initialize() {
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'), { types: ['(cities)'], componentRestrictions : { country: 'in' }});

        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="locationField">
      <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is my answer solved your problem ?

Comment: Thanks AlexB. but its not an good solution so I just up-voted your answer

Comment: What else do you need, if it's not a good solution for you Amit ?

Comment: I don't want to use the CSS, Actually Google may be change it any time...Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can't *remove* these informations, however, you can *mask* them using CSS.

Please refer to [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#style_autocomplete).

To quote the official documentation, here are the classes used by the components of the `Autocomplete`.
[image]

So I suggest you to use CSS to hide the part(s) you don't want to display.
In your case, you can use :

```
.pac-item-query + span
{
    display: none
}
```

This will hide the next [adjacent](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) `<span>` to the `<span>` whose class is `pac-item-query` (which contains the suggested name of the city only), and so, only let the city displayed.
Thus, the state / country is masked, as you required.

**Be careful**, the `+` pseudo-selector is not supported by all browsers, including IE6.  Please check your browser requirements before using it.